# Woocommerce send metadata to stripe

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field

I am using woocommerce checkout and woocommerce stripe payment plugin, I want to send metadata to stripe from woocommerce order the [billing_vat_number]

Can anyone tell me how its done, it is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugins' support teams about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.